# How to stop gazebo publishing tf

Tags: ros, gazebo, navigation, gmapping, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all!

Now I'm testing the node /robot_pose_ekf with gazebo simulator. And I have already let /gazebo publish IMU and odometry data to /robot_pose_ekf. Also, /robot_pose_ekf is connected to tf.

However, when I checked the tf tree I found that the transform from odom -> base_footprint was provided by /gazebo but I want it to be /robot_pose_ekf.

I guess it is because both /gazebo and /robot_pose_ekf are publishing /tf. Hence, I think stopping /gazebo publishing /tf can be a possible solution. FYI, I'm using GMapping which subscribes to /tf to provide SLAM functions.

Can anyone tell me how to stop gazebo publishing tf? Or any other solutions to my problem?

Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229722/how-to-stop-gazebo-publishing-tf/) by [Clack](https://answers.ros.org/users/25357/clack/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2016-03-21

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2016-03-21**:
An alternative approach is to keep the odom->base_footprint as it is and compensate the odometry drift by adjusting the transform world->odom or map->odom then you just consider the transform world->base_footprint as robot pose. AFAIK this is what happens when you perform localization using i.e AMCL

**Comment by [Clack](https://answers.ros.org/users/25357/clack/) on 2016-03-21**:
Thanks to your advice, Mehdi. But actually I have a laser scanner used to provide map -> odom. And my goal is to let robot_pose_ekf provide odom -> base_footprint instead of /gazebo itself. The reason why I stick to this is because I have to check if robot_pose_ekf can be used with GMapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use remapping method to map from `tf` to something like `gazebo_tf`, just add the remapping tags:
`<remap from="tf" to="gazebo_tf"/>` in the launch file of the empty world.

For example:

`<node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="gzserver" respawn="false" output="screen" args="-e ode worlds/empty.world" > <remap from="tf" to="gazebo_tf"/>  </node>`

---

Originally posted by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) with karma: 544 on 2016-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Clack](https://answers.ros.org/users/25357/clack/) on 2016-03-21**:
Thanks a lot! I'll have a try tomorrow as soon as I get back to my lab :)

**Comment by [Clack](https://answers.ros.org/users/25357/clack/) on 2016-03-22**:
It works! Thank you so much!

**Comment by [lifuguan](https://answers.ros.org/users/45008/lifuguan/) on 2020-08-03**:
What confused me is that although I add `<remap from="tf" to="gazebo_tf"/>` as you mentioned, tf `odom` still exist.

```
<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find autonomus_transport_industrial_system)/worlds/obstacle_map.world"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
    <remap from="tf" to="gazebo_tf"/>
</include>
```

rostopic info tf display:

```
    Type: tf2_msgs/TFMessage

Publishers: 
 * /robot_state_publisher (http://localhost:46447/)
 * /camera_front (http://localhost:35855/)
 * /camera_right (http://localhost:43249/)
 * /camera_left (http://localhost:33375/)
 * /gazebo (http://localhost:37939/)

Subscribers: 
 * /rviz (http://localhost:33813/)
```

**Comment by [shrini96](https://answers.ros.org/users/104316/shrini96/) on 2023-02-07**:
@lifuguan remap does not work inside the include tags. Either put it inside the node like @DavidN shows, or before the includes.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to DavidN, my problem is solved :)

Now the node /robot_pose_ekf is providing the transform odom -> base_footprint instead of /gazebo.

FYI, my modification to `/opt/ros/indigo/share/gazebo_ros/launch/empty_world.launch` is a little bit different than what DavidN has mentioned:

```
<!-- start gazebo server-->
  <node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="gzserver" respawn="false" output="screen" 
    args="$(arg command_arg1) $(arg command_arg2) $(arg command_arg3) $(arg world_name)">    
  <remap from="tf" to="gazebo_tf"/> 
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [Clack](https://answers.ros.org/users/25357/clack/) with karma: 75 on 2016-03-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevekung](https://answers.ros.org/users/66199/stevekung/) on 2020-12-23**:
请问一下老哥最后是怎么解决的呀，我碰到一模一样的问题 谢谢~ 修改完后之后 tf的确去除掉了，但是 gazebo小车模型在不停的抖动

**Comment by [SeanZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/67621/seanz/) on 2021-01-12**:
In most cases,  the robot model shaking because you are providing more than one odometry.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your are using a differential drive controller plugin for your robot then you can prevent Gazebo from publishing the odom transfrom by setting `publishOdomTF` to `false`

```
<gazebo>
    <plugin name="differential_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
        ...
        <publishOdomTF>false</publishOdomTF>
        ...
    </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

---

Originally posted by [Subodh Malgonde](https://answers.ros.org/users/36410/subodh-malgonde/) with karma: 512 on 2018-08-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2